# C#: Unix timestamp and DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timestamp

we are developing a C# web application that has to deal with Unix timestamps and C# DateTime objects. A timestamp has to be converted into a DateTime object.

The following example shows my problem: The DateTime should be '18.10.2011 14:02:32'

```
System.DateTime time = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
time = time.AddSeconds(1318939352);
System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Time: " + time); // -> 18.10.2011 12:02:32
```

If I call ToLocalTime() on my developer machine, the DateTime is correct:

```
System.DateTime time = new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
time = time.AddSeconds(1318939352).ToLocalTime();
System.Console.Out.WriteLine("Time: " + time); // -> 18.10.2011 14:02:32
```

But the application will run on servers which are hosted in another timezone (GMT Standard Time), so I have to deal with a different time zone and the second example fails on this servers.
Independent of where I host the application, the date in this case should always be printed as 18.10.2011 14:02:32.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks in advance!

Best Regards,
Thorsten

Comment: Why not specify  `DateTimeKind.Utc` when you make the instance, does that work ? like `new System.DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,DateTimeKind.Utc);` (hoping 14:02:32 is GMT)

Comment: always store times in UTC, it is the responsibility of the client application to tell the server how it wants the time formatted for output.

Comment: @V4Vendetta - 14:02:32 is GMT + 2

Comment: Your unix timestamp is already in local time. This is your problem.

Comment: @Xanatos: If my unix timestamp is already in local time, what would you do so that the DateTime is correct?

Comment: The Unix timestamp should be GMT (or UTC). The Windows time is usually local time. So a difference should be because of timezones.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx)

```
public struct DateTimeWithZone
{
    private readonly DateTime utcDateTime;
    private readonly TimeZoneInfo timeZone;

    public DateTimeWithZone(DateTime dateTime, TimeZoneInfo timeZone)
    {
        utcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(dateTime, timeZone); 
        this.timeZone = timeZone;
    }

    public DateTime UniversalTime 
    { 
       get {  return utcDateTime; } 
    }

    public TimeZoneInfo TimeZone 
    { 
       get { return timeZone; } 
    }

    public DateTime LocalTime
    { 
        get { return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(utcDateTime, timeZone); }
    }        
}
```